# setattribute name starts with number

Tags: php, xml, setattribute

I have a php file that outputs xml. It works unless I put lines in where the name starts with a number. I looked around but couldn't find that it was illegal. Is there something I'm missing?

```
$newnode->setAttribute("20amp", $row["20amp"]);
```

The server is reporting an error 500. but I haven't tracked down a more specific error yet. Only that if I comment this line out it works. I'd really like to keep my sql field names in the xml name.

Comment: Look in the log file what the exact error message is.

Comment: Attribute names cannot start with digits in XML: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameStartChar (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Attribute).

Comment: I'm using this in an ajax call from a web page. Is there another way to keep my database field names intact while getting my data from a php page?

Comment: I changed from xml to json and that solved the problem of the names starting with numbers.